# re.sub() wildcard string replacement

Tags: python, regex

Here is the source string, it has two wildcards `<1>` and `<2>`, both are arbitrary number of digits.

```
SomeText<1>_<2>.value
```

I need to transform the above string into this one, with `<1>` and `<2>` replaced by exact same digits found in source string.

```
SomeOtherText_<2>r962<1>xyz
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that this expression is likely to do that:

```
import re
regex = r"^.*?<(\d+)>_<(\d+)>.*$"
test_str = """

SomeText<192>_<283>.value
    SomeText<>_<>.value
    SomeOtherText_<192>r962<283>xyz
"""
subst = "SomeOtherText_<\\1>r962<\\2>xyz"

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4V35ot/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/4V35ot/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. All I needed was to remove '>' and '<' from the regex variable, as I used those angle brackets to mention wildcards in my question